# mvn test Cannot find class in classpath

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

Java, Selenium, TestNG, Maven
Have a project at local machine and its copy on git. When I'm running the project on local - the test runs successfully (with mvn test command). But once the project got cloned from git and being run on another local (or even on my local, but saved into another folder) it throws an error:

```
Cannot find class in classpath: packagename.Login
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an 
error in the forked process

Cannot find class in classpath: packagename.Login
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I'm using mvn test command in cmd.

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>src</groupId>
<artifactId>AutomationTestSuit</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>AutomationTestSuit</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium- 
java -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
         <version>3.11.0</version>
     </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>6.14.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.17</version>
     </dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
         <version>3.17</version>
     </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->

     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
          <version>3.17</version>
     </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-examples -->
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
   </dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-excelant -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
       <version>3.17</version>
   </dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
         <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
         <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.saucelabs/sauce_testng -->
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>sauce_testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.23</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
             <configuration>
                 <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                 <suiteXmlFiles>               

 <suiteXmlFile>C:\Users\****\testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                 </suiteXmlFiles>                  
            </configuration>
     </plugin>
 </plugins>

</build>
```

testng.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="2" parallel="methods" thread- 
count="2">    
<test name="Regression" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">

    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <parameter name="OS" value="Windows 7"/>
    <parameter name="version" value="64"/>
    <parameter name="sauceLabsUsername" value="**"/>
    <parameter name="accesskey" value="***"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="packagename.Login"/>                    
    </classes>
</test> 
</suite>
```

Class:

```
package packagename;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login extends Remote {

@Test

public void Login() throws Exception {


LoginPage.Login_as(ConfigFileReader.getUserName(), 
ConfigFileReader.getPassword());
Log.info("User successfully logged on");
}
```